# how do i wait to get the response from img.onload

Tags: jquery

THE CHECKSIZE FUNCTION RETURNS UNDEFINED---
    immediately it hits img.onload it jumps to the end of checksize

```
function checksize(files) 
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
    var sizes = {
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height
    };
    if (sizes.width != 600 || sizes.height != 800) 
    {
        alert("Error: Image size should be 600 x 800px");
        return false;

    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing closing braces for the main function due to which your `img.src` is inside the img.load which is wrong, change it to look like following and you are comparing exact length so only the exact dimension image would return true i have changed the code a little bit to append the images to the body once they are loaded and i changed the condition `if (sizes.width != 600 || sizes.height != 800)` to `if (sizes.width <= 600 || sizes.height <= 800) {` so the images that are smaller than the `800 x 600` are not appended to the body and the error is thrown on the `console` you can change the condition back

```
function checksize(files) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    var sizes = {
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height
    };

    if (sizes.width <= 600 || sizes.height <= 800) {
      console.log("Error: Image size should be greater 600 x 800px , image " + img.src + ' could not be loaded');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('body').append(img);
      return true;
    }

  };
  img.src = files;

}
```

```js
function checksize(files) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    var sizes = {
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height
    };

    if (sizes.width <= 600 || sizes.height <= 800) {
      console.log("Error: Image size should be greater 600 x 800px , image " + img.src + ' could not be loaded');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('body').append(img);
      return true;
    }

  };
  img.src = files;

}

var files = ['https://www.animalfriends.co.uk/app/uploads/2017/04/21150218/iStock-524369488.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/356378/pexels-photo-356378.jpeg', 'https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/238/large/44186f3f7c3e962827e462a95d7206bc.jpg'];

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  checksize(files[i]);
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an event handler to the load event of an image element. Do this instead

```
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).on("load",function(){
      var sizes = {
       width: this.width,
       height: this.height
       };
      if (sizes.width != 600 || sizes.height != 800) 
      {
         alert("Error: Image size should be 600 x 800px");
         return false;

      }
     else 
     {
       return true;
     }


    });
   img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
```

Note that you need to place the img.src after the event function if you want to trigger the function when the image is set. Placing it inside the function will cause recursion